# Unable to start bash script with shell_exec

Tags: linux, bash, php

I've been googling and trying to solve this problem with my php script for a few days now and I'm hoping someone here can see the problem I'm missing in getting my php script to kick off my bash script.

Here's my php:

```
//kickoff the yapeal script
echo "Starting yapeal.sh<br>";
echo "Current working directory: ";
echo getcwd() . "\n";
shell_exec('./yapeal.sh');
echo "<br>yapeal.sh ran, I hope.<br>";
```

Here is the yapeal.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/tools/applications
php -f /var/www/lib/yapeal/yapeal.php
sleep 5s
echo "`date -u` Yapeal kicked off, working" > bashoutput.log 2>&1
```

Here's the perms on the files:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 4640 Jul 10 07:20 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 2845 Jul 10 07:33 working.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  232 Jul 10 07:17 yapeal.sh
```

Here is what I get as an output in the web browser:

```
Starting yapeal.sh
Current working directory: /var/www/tools/applications
yapeal.sh ran, I hope.
```

There's no output to the bashoutput.log file.

I've checked my php.ini, there is no reference to exec or shell_exec in the disable_functions section.

Comment: I solved my own problem.

Modified the php code to:

    $output = shell_exec('./yapeal.sh');
    echo $output;

Comment: You should soon (or now?) be able to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem.

Modified the php code to:

```
$output = shell_exec('./yapeal.sh');
echo $output;
```